# Determining slopes with R code

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have a number of melting curves, for which I want to determine the slope of the steepest part between the minimum (valley) and maximum (peak) using R code (the slope in the inflection point corresponds to the melting point). The solutions I can imagine are either to determine the slope in every point and then find the maximum positive value, or by fitting a 4-parameter Weibull-type curve using the drc package to determine the inflection point (basically corresponding to the 50% response point between minimum and maximum). In the latter case the tricky part is that this fitting has to be restricted for each curve to the temperature range between the minimum (valley) and maximum (peak) fluorescence response. These temperature ranges are different for each curve.

Grateful for any feedback!

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking about the best statistical method or are you having problems writing the code?

Comment: "Steepest part"  will depend heavily on how you choose to do noise reduction (smoothing) on your data.

Comment: Melting of what?  Packages `MBmca` and `qpcR` handle melting of nucleic acids.  Maybe you can use them, or at least some of the ideas therein.

Comment: I would like to see an example R code. There is no noise. It's melting curves of a protein determined with differential scanning fluorimetry, with 1.0 degrees temperature increments between 25 and 90 degrees Celsius.

Comment: I don't know how to break it to you, but if you made measurements then you have noise.  There's no such thing as a perfect measurement (or perfect lab instruments).

Comment: Well, I'm not concerned about noise, if any (it certainly isn't visible in my data, so if there is any I am confident I can safely ignore it). There is between-sample variability, but that is compensated for by intermittent blank controls for which the mean and st.dev. of the melting point will be determined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diff function accomplishes the equivalent of numerical differentiation on equally spaced values (up to a constant factor) so finding  maximum (or minimum) values can be used to identify location of steepest ascent (or descent):

```
z <- exp(-seq(0,3, by=0.1)^2 )
plot(z)
plot(diff(z))
z[ which(abs(diff(z))==max(abs(diff(z))) )]
# [1] 0.6126264
# could have also tested for min() instead of max(abs())
plot(z)
abline( v = which(abs(diff(z))==max(abs(diff(z))) ) )
abline( h = z[which(abs(diff(z))==max(abs(diff(z))) ) ] )
```

[image]

With an x-difference of 1, the slope is just the difference at that point:

```
diff(z) [ which(abs(diff(z))==max(abs(diff(z))) )  ]
[1] -0.08533397
```

... but I question whether that is really of much interest. I would have thought that getting the index (which would be the melting point subject to an offset) would be the value of interest.

Comment: `which.max` might make that a bit simpler.