# calculating slope values from splines

Tags: r

I would like to obtain the x and y values at points where the slope is maximal and minimal on a spline.  I saw how to do that at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430233/determining-slopes-with-r-code), but could not replicate it on my dataset.  They can make use of `diff()` but my dataset has specific x and y vectors.  My data typically looks like this:

`x<-c(0, 0.13, 0.22, 0.34, 0.44, 0.53, 0.62, 0.72, 0.83, 0.91)
y<-c(120, 121, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 121, 119, 103)
z <-data.frame(x, y)
z
plot(z)
xspline(z$x,z$y, shape=0.5)`

But of course I cannot use this:

`w <-xspline(z$x,z$y, shape=0.5)
plot(diff(w))`

If I could, I would do this:

`param1 <- which(abs(diff(w))==max(abs(diff(w))) )
param2 <-z[which(abs(diff(w))==max(abs(diff(w))) ) ]
param1 <- which(abs(diff(w))==min(abs(diff(w))) )
param2 <-z[which(abs(diff(w))==min(abs(diff(w))) ) ]`

I would be grateful for advice on a different way to get that plot of slopes, or alternatively another way to get these parameters.  Perhaps I have gone too far down the 'splines' road.

Comment: maybe `numDeriv(splinefun())`  ?

Comment: Mm, `??numDeriv` gives me no results.  splinefun sounds like the business though.  I will keep on.

Comment: Thanks  @Carl Witthoft I managed to post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
w <-data.frame(xspline(z$x,z$y, shape=0.5, draw=F))
```

that will make `w` a data.frame with the `x` and `y` values used to draw the spline. Then you can take the max/min of the differences in `y` to estimate the maximal and minimal slope points

```
plot(z)
with(w, lines(x,y))
with(w[which.max(diff(w$y)),], points(x,y,col="red"))
with(w[which.min(diff(w$y)),], points(x,y,col="blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I managed to use this to get my required results.  Actually this is the second time you have helped me, so 'thanks again'.  I also just managed to follow up on Carl Witthoft 's answer, and I will post another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the clue given by @Carl Witthoft I installed the package `numDeriv` so I could use `grad()`, and continued where I left off previously:

```
`plot(splinefun(z, method="monoH.F")) #just to check the shape of the spline
w <-splinefun(z, method="monoH.F")
z$slopes <-grad(w, z$x, method="simple")
z
plot(z$slopes~z$x) #just out of interest
max.slope <- subset(z, slopes==max(z$slopes))
max.slope.y <-max.slope$y[1]
max.slope.x <-max.slope$x[1]`
```

Maybe not so elegant, but did the trick.  I have noted the slight different in the shape of the splines between `splinefun()` and `xspline()`, which may or may not be relevant to my application.